# Water Pressure Issue? First water heater leaked, then softener, now my washer long filled

Tags: water, water-pressure

My water heater was leaking from the top.  I replaced it.

The next day, the water softener tank is leaking.  I turned off the valve to bypass the softener.

Now my washing machine (brand new) errored with *LF* which means "Long Fill"; a repairman replaced the fill valves and mentioned that they were faulty and it is a rarity that it happens.

My research found that a softener with a heater leak means there is too much water pressure.  LF errors on washing machine potentially mean that the water pressure is too low.

I'm scratching my head on this one...  The pressure in the toilet, sinks and shower seem fine.  The pressure slightly increased when I got the new water heater.  I am worried that there is some underlying pressure issue in my home.  Please suggest some solutions or tips.

Comment: Does the building have a water pressure regulator?  Have you hooked up a pressure gauge and measured the pressure?  One like [this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/3-4-in-Plastic-Water-Pressure-Test-Gauge-DP-IWTG/100175467) shows maximum pressure.

Answer (score 2):

You did not say, if the washer fill problem was fixed with the new valves. Sometimes, when you turn off the water to the house to make a repair, sediment or debris is loosened somewhere in the plumbing when the water is turned back on. Did you check the inlet screens at the hose connections of the washing machine. This debris will plug the screens  (a common problem). Also make sure that all the valves for the water to the washer are fully open. As far as two appliances leaking it is probably a coincidence. The research with " the softener with the heater leak means there is too much pressure" makes no sense. Any of the above mentioned problem items could cause the error message.